# What's the magic behind int64_t

Tags: c++, c, gcc, c89

- In `C89` `long long` doesn't exist (it was added in `C99`)
- In `C++03`(and `C++98`) `long long` doesn't exist (it was added in `C++11`)

Now if I compile this:

```
typedef long long myType;

int main()
{
   myType a;
}
```

with (`g++ sourceFile.cpp -std=c++03 -pedantic` OR `gcc sourceFile.c -std=c89 -pedantic`) it will give warning that currently chosen standard does not support `long long`

However, if I compile this (with same flags):

```
#include <stdint.h> //in case of C
#include <cstdint> //in case of C++

int main()
{
    int64_t a;
}
```

I won't get any warnings even if `stdint.h` (`cstdint` just includes `stdint.h` and make names visible inside `std`)  contains

```
...
typedef long long int64_t;
...
```

I'm wondering how this can work.

Comment: Isn't `stdint.h` for C library..?, Take a look at `cstdint`.

Comment: Just because a language standard doesn't require a particular data type to be present doesn't mean that any given implementation (GCC in this case) cannot implement it. I'd assume that GCC doesn't warn about well-known files (those, that ship as part of the implementation). I'm not really sure, what question you are asking, though.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, that should be answer. I was just interested why this works.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html

Comment: `What's the magic behind int64_t?` -- it is specified to be a signed 64 bit value on all systems.

Comment: @David: ... on all systems that have a 64-bit integer type.

Comment: @Hurkyl: *"on all systems that have a 64-bit integer type."* - No. On all platforms. If it cannot be represented in a native fashion, the implementation (compiler and support libraries) must mimic the behavior (just like floating point numbers on systems that don't have native floating point support).

Comment: @IInspectable: not true. Specified-width integer types are optional, see section 7.20.1.1 paragraph 3 of the C11 standard or any reliable reference.

Comment: @rici: That may be the case, but it's not the system (OS) that decides, whether a language implementation has a 64 bit integer type or not. It's the implementation, and if a system cannot natively represent a 64-bit integer, the implementation must emulate it.

Comment: @IInspectable. Why? The standard specifically says the implementation does not need to emulate the types if they don't exist.

Comment: @rici: But it's still the implementation that gets to decide. Hurkyl makes it sound, like it is the OS, and that is not the case. An implementation can still decide to implement an optional feature, even if the system has no native support for it. Which part do you not agree with?

Comment: The word "must". That would imply that it is required, but it is not. And by the way, "system" is not a synonym of "OS".

Comment: @IInspectable: Consider a non-8bit machine. Let's say one with 24-bit words. *There is no 64-bit integer on such a machine*. While `uint_least64_t` and `uint_fast64_t` would still be defined on such a hardware, `uint64_t` wouldn't. That the standard makes the exact-width types *optional* is to allow for exactly such a machine to have a fully-compliant C implementation. Which is also why using the exact-width types everywhere, in places where the *exact* width is not really necessary, is actually a poor design choice.

Comment: @DevSolar. That's nothing new. The point I'm trying to make, however, is, that it is the compiler (or the implementation rather) that decides, not the system/hardware/architecture. You can implement a 64-bit integer type on a system, that has a 24-bit word. It'd generate more code to simulate a 64-bit integer type on this hypothetical system, but it is possible, in the same way you can implement floating point math in software on system that don't have dedicated FPU hardware.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I won't get any warnings even if stdint.h...

That is because GCC, by default, does not generate warnings for system headers. You can order it to do so via the command line option `-Wsystem-headers`...